# Tableview reloaddata is not working when embedded function called from another view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am experiencing a weird behavior of tableview, I am building an app where when clicked on ADD will present a modal view controller which is a subclass of UATitledModalPanel where I just present some textfield to insert info from the user.

When they click on Submit the data will be sent to mainviewcontroller's function which saves the data to DataBase and try to reload the tableview which I made programatically. However in this above process, the tableview does not get reloaded. But if do the same procedure from a buton in the viewcontroller it does this correctly. Below is the code of my view controller.

**ViewController.h**

```
 @interface ViewController :      UIViewController<UAModalPanelDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate,UITextViewDelegate,UITableViewData Source,UITableViewDelegate>{
DataClass *dataOfValue;
}
@property(strong,nonatomic)UITableView *table;
-(void)reloadDatas;
-(void)insertData:(NSString *)gettingData;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@interface ViewController (){
NSMutableArray *data;
DataClass *dataclass;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize table;
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-64.0f) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.view addSubview:table];
[table registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
self.navigationItem.title = @"Scheduler";
self.table.delegate = self;
self.table.dataSource = self;
//self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
UIImageView *infoimg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"detail.png"]];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoimg];

UITapGestureRecognizer *infotap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(addAction:)];
[infotap setAccessibilityLabel:@"infotap"];
infotap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

[infoimg addGestureRecognizer:infotap];

UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"]];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:img];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(addAction:)];
[tap setAccessibilityLabel:@"tap"];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

[img addGestureRecognizer:tap];

table.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table_background.jpg"]];

//UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] i]
 table.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation_bar.jpg"]];

[self openDataBase];

}

- (void)openDataBase{
data = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"callsmsDB.sqlite"];
FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
[database open];
FMResultSet *res = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM data"];
int i = 0;
while ([res next]) {
    i++;
    //NSLog(@"%@",[res stringForColumn:@"status"]);
    dataclass = [[DataClass alloc] init];
    dataclass.identifier = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[res intForColumn:@"id"]];
    dataclass.number = [res stringForColumn:@"number"];
    dataclass.date = [res stringForColumn:@"date"];
    dataclass.type = [res stringForColumn:@"type"];
    dataclass.description = [res stringForColumn:@"description"];
    dataclass.status = [res stringForColumn:@"status"];
    [data addObject:dataclass];

}
NSLog(@"The size of the array is %d",[data count]);
NSLog(@"The value of is %d",i);
[self.table performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:self.table waitUntilDone:YES];

[database close];
}

- (void)addAction:(id)sender{
UIGestureRecognizer *infotag = (UIGestureRecognizer *) sender;
NSString *info = infotag.accessibilityLabel;
if([info isEqualToString:@"infotap"]){
    //NSLog(@"About app");
    //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"appinfo" sender:self];
    /*AboutApp *nextController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"aboutapp"];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: nextController animated:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];*/
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(openDataBase) withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];

   }else{
    [self showModalPanel:sender];

   }
   }

  -(void)showModalPanel:(id)sender{

UAExampleModalPanel *modalPanel = [[UAExampleModalPanel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame title:@"Schedule a Task"] ;

   int blocksDelegateOrNone = arc4random() % 3;

if (0 == blocksDelegateOrNone) {
    // The block is responsible for closing the panel,
    //   either with -[UAModalPanel hide] or -[UAModalPanel hideWithOnComplete:]
    //   Panel is a reference to the modalPanel
    modalPanel.onClosePressed = ^(UAModalPanel* panel) {
        // [panel hide];
        [panel hideWithOnComplete:^(BOOL finished) {
            [panel removeFromSuperview];
        }];
        UADebugLog(@"onClosePressed block called from panel: %@", modalPanel);
    };

    //   Panel is a reference to the modalPanel
    modalPanel.onActionPressed = ^(UAModalPanel* panel) {
        UADebugLog(@"onActionPressed block called from panel: %@", modalPanel);
    };

    UADebugLog(@"UAModalView will display using blocks: %@", modalPanel);

    // USE DELEGATE
         } else if (1 == blocksDelegateOrNone) {
    // Add self as the delegate so we know how to close the panel
    modalPanel.delegate = self;

    UADebugLog(@"UAModalView will display using delegate methods: %@", modalPanel);

    // USE NOTHING
        } else {
    // no-op. No delegate or blocks
    UADebugLog(@"UAModalView will display without blocks or delegate methods: %@", modalPanel);
}

// Add the panel to our view
[self.view addSubview:modalPanel];

// Show the panel from the center of the button that was pressed
[modalPanel showFromPoint:self.view.bounds.origin];
    }
   -(void)insertData:(NSString *)gettingData{
//NSLog(@"data is %@",gettingData);
    NSString *number;
    NSString *date;
    NSString *type;
    NSString *description;
    NSString *status;
    NSArray *myString = [gettingData componentsSeparatedByString:@"@@"];
//NSLog(@"%@",myString);
number = [myString objectAtIndex:0];
date = [myString objectAtIndex:1];
type = [myString objectAtIndex:2];
description = [myString objectAtIndex:3];
status  = @"active";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"callsmsDB.sqlite"];
FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
[database open];
BOOL b = [database executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO data(number,date,type,description,status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",number, date, type, description,status];
  if(b)
    NSLog(@"Successfully inserted.");
    int i = [database lastInsertRowId];
    NSLog(@"last inserted id is %i",i);
    [database close];
   [self openDataBase];


   }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@"The value of count of data is %d",[data count]);
UIImage *typeImage;
CustomCell *cell;
if(cell == nil)
    cell =  (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
// Configure Cell
DataClass *recent = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//NSLog(@"jjj %@",recent.description);
if ([recent.type isEqualToString:@"call"]) {
    typeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"call.png"];
}else{
    typeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sms.png"];
}
[cell.mylabel setText:recent.number];
[cell.corsms setImage:typeImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *delImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"delete.png"];
[cell.detail setImage:delImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
if([recent.status isEqualToString:@"Active"]){
    [cell.myswitch setOn:YES];
}else{
    [cell.myswitch setOn:NO];
}
[cell.myswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
return cell;
}


 - (void)changeSwitch:(id)sender{

NSString *status;
RCSwitchOnOff *sw = (RCSwitchOnOff *)sender;
CustomCell *custcell = (CustomCell *)sw.superview.superview;
UITableView *tableview = (UITableView *)custcell.superview;
NSInteger rowOfTheCell = [[tableview indexPathForCell:custcell] row];
//NSLog(@"%i",rowOfTheCell);
if([sw isOn]){
    status = @"Active";
}else{
    status = @"Inactive";
}
NSLog(@"%@",status);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"callsmsDB.sqlite"];
FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
[database open];
[database executeUpdate:@"UPDATE data SET status = ? WHERE id = ?",status,[[data objectAtIndex:rowOfTheCell] identifier]];
[database close];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section          {
NSLog(@"Number of rows in section = %d",[data count]);
return [data count];
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return YES;
 }
```

**in ModalViewController**

I create an instance of ViewController and call the insertData however it does not reload the table. But if I attach a bar button to my navigation bar and call table reload it does work.

I don't not want to make a refresh button to reload the table.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create an instance of ViewController in ModalViewController. Its wrong. Instead you can create a protocol and delegate the notification.
You can get more details from below link.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm